# How to create fullscreen for layouts in android 6.0?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, fullscreen

My app works fine in the previous version of Android system, but in the current version it doesn't scale the views (programmatically created) to the dimension of screen using

`@ android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Didi you try [Activity(Label = "My Activity", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"]

Comment: Your question is vague. I don't understand what exactly do you mean by full screen, is it that you want to get rid of the title bar or status bar?